# handling download dialog window in IE using Selenium & java

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, download

Can anyone help me out on handling download dialog window in IE using Selenium & java. thank you.

Comment: Check this http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/downloading-a-file-in-internet-explorer-through-selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157 this approach is quite bulky, but works fine for different cases

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-csv.php");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[4]/a")).click();
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Using Robot Class you can use key events for handling UI Which opens when you click on download button.

Just Execute the code you will find this useful. Another tool you can use is "AutoIt". It is better than Robot Class.

Answer (score 0):

blogger link for handling download page :[Steps to handle download page IEDriver with code](https://seleniumquestionssolutions.blogspot.com/2023/10/how-to-open-or-handle-download-page-in.html)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\ Desktop\\Automation\\edgedriver_win64\\msedgedriver.exe");
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.bing.com/");
 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
   driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
     
    
    driver.get("edge://downloads/all");
```

This is solution for opening download page I have work microsoft edge web driver I think this will be work for other browser also

Comment: open download page on the different tab of the Internet Explorer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).